# Different aws_security_group egress rules depending on user-input (terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

I am trying to figure out how to have different egress rules depending on the variable supplied. For my use case, the security group should either have full outbound access to the world, or be removed entirely.

Currently I am manually commenting out one rule versus the other when I need to make these changes but ideally I'd like to control this by using a variable or some other user-supplied means.

When I need egress open to the world:

```
  resource "aws_security_group" "test" {
    ...
    egress {
      from_port        = 0
      to_port          = 0
      protocol         = "-1"
      cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
      ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]
    }
    ...
```

When I need all egress rules removed entirely:

```
  resource "aws_security_group" "test" {
    ...
    egress = []
    ...
```

Comment: Look into dynamic blocks https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be best to use `aws_security_group_rule` and `count`:

```
variable "enable_egress" {
  type = bool
  default = true
}


resource "aws_security_group" "test" {

}

resource "aws_security_group_rule" "example" {

  security_group_id = aws_security_group.test.id

  count = var.enable_egress == true ? 1 : 0

  type              = "egress"
  from_port        = 0
  to_port          = 0
  protocol         = "-1"
  cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"] 
}
```

Comment: @supanooba No problem. Glad the answer helped.